# Why this C program behaves abnormally when the function is called as an argument

Tags: c, recursion

I created a program to calculate the power of a number.
Please look into the working code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int power(int,int);

    int main()
    {
        int num,n;
        scanf("%d %d",&num,&n);
        printf("power of %d to %d\n",num,n);

        printf("%d",power(num,n));
        return 0;
    }

    int power(int num,int n)
    {
        int result=0;
        if(n==0)
            return 1;
        if(n==1)
            return num;
        if(n%2!=0)
        {
            result=num*power(num,n-1);
        }
        else if(n%2==0)
        {
            result=power(num,n/2)*power(num,n/2); 
//why this hangs when i replace this statement with power(power(num,n/2),2)
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This program works fine as long as I don't replace the last statement with the one mentioned in the comments.

Could you please let me know the reason behind this abnormal behaviour?

Comment: Because `power(..., 2)` will always recursively call `power(..., 2)`.

Comment: You could drastically reduce the number of calls to `power` for large `n` by replacing that last `else if` block with `{ int tmp=power(num,n/2); result=tmp*tmp; }`

Answer (score 1):

> This program works fine as long as I don't replace the last statement
>   with the one mentioned in the comments.
>
> Could you please let me know the reason behind this abnormal
>   behaviour?

This isn't abnormal behavior.

```
power(power(num,n/2),2)
```

Is a recursive call where the base case is never reached because `n == 2` therefore the else if clause for `n % 2 == 0` is always going to be executed.